# Адаптивная Верстка - помогите с практикой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Изучил более менее `Html & css`, практиковался на статичных сайтах. Теперь хочу начать изучать адаптивную верстку. Перечитал пару десятков сайтов об этом, и до меня плохо доходит. Может, кто скинуть максимально простой макет с адаптивной версткой, просто одни блоки, без надписей, картинок и прочего, теорию знаю но на практике не могу ее применить, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Откройте любой простой сайт в браузерном инспекторе и любуйтесь кодом. Можете его скачать с помощью расширения Save All Resources для хрома и повозиться в файлах

Comment: @Veeven Приветствуем Вас на Stackoverflow! Чтобы Ваш вопрос не закрыли, почитайте здесь [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Это займет не более минуты Добавьте в сниппет любой код вашей неудавшейся попытки Именно код добавьте, а не скрин кода. Уважайте отвечающих, чтобы им не пришлось набивать код со скрина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то с флексами

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card__item>*+* {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card__item {
  width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .card__item {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .card__item {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card__container">

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- .card__container -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Что-то с гридами

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 200px));
  grid-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card__item>*+* {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.card__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card__container">

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card__item">
      <div class="card__title">
        Заголовок
      </div>
      <div class="card__img">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- .card__container -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```